# Taking the exponent of a SHA3 hash function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha-3

I am trying to implement a protocol described in the paper [Private Data Aggregation with Groups for Smart Grids in a Dynamic Setting using CRT](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7368584/) in python.

In order to do this, I need to calculate the following value:

[image]

I know that since python 3.6, you can calculate a SHA3 value as follows:

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.sha3_512(b'value_to_encode')
hash_value = hash_object.hexdigest()
```

I was wondering you should solve this, since, as far as I know, a SHA-3 function returns a string and therefore cannot be calculated in a function with to the power of n.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: When you pass a string data type to python's internal hash functions I would use the method: a_string_data_type.encode('utf-8'). You can have silent failure without the encoding step with some versions of python.

Comment: @back_seat_driver: `b'value_to_encode'` is not a string type, it's a bytes object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define a hash function $H: \{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^n$, that is one that produces an $n$ bit output, we can always interpret the binary data $h$ that it outputs as an integer. The integer value of this digest is $\sum_{i=0}^n h_i 2^i$, in other words the digest is a base 2 representation of the integer.

In your case, since python has a notion of types, we need to take the binary string and convert it to an integer type. The builtin `int` function can do this for us:

> int(x=0) -> integer
>
> int(x, base=10) -> integer
>
> Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
>   are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
>   numbers, this truncates towards zero.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
>   bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the
>   given base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded
>   by whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
>   Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
>
> >>> int('0b100', base=0)
>
> 4

The `hexdigest` call will return a hex string which is base 16, so you would want to do something like `int_value = int(hash_value, 16)`.

Comment: The `.digest()` method will output a bytes object, so constructing the int using [`int.from_bytes(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) is another option that is probably a bit faster. Of course string conversion to/from hex is much faster than to/from decimal, so the difference should be minimal.